# How to import excel spreadsheet to SharePoint document library?

Tags: excel, sharepoint-server

Excel spreadsheet has several columns including a filename column which has actual path to file, that file should is exactly I want to be imported to document library. Once imported the filename column should be a link, which when clicked opens the associated file, the files obviously will need importing too.

Here is sample excel file including files.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/oz5vhd0hs3du24e/Sharepoint_Import.rar

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a SharePoint library the data object is the file so you cannot simply import an Excel file to create a library.

You could potentially create your library with appropriate columns, import the files and then paste in the metadata through the datasheet view.

Another option could be to create a PowerShell script to loop through each item in your Excel file (may be as CSV) and import the file on the path setting the related metadata.

Comment: I am new to SharePoint. Would you please suggest me some link where I could find how to write PowerShell script to loop items in Excel. Thanks

Comment: I am no expert either but there are plenty of PowerShell resources on the web - good luck with it